# Kernel of a $C^2$ function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, notation, mathematical-physics, constraints

I have found the following description on some notes of mathematical physics:

I have the classical equation for constraints $\Phi(x)=0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, with $\Phi \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^{d-m})$ with $rgD\Phi$ is max in every point. Then these notes continues like that: "*...the kernel of $\Phi$ has to be $m$-dimensional...*"

I know that the question seems to be too much general, but what is the kernel of a general application like the one above? I mean, in this paper there are not more information about $\Phi$, what I have written is all we know about $\Phi$ and I didn't find anything about Ker of applications which are not linear or preserve "rigid" structure.

Comment: In finite dimensional spaces the kernel is $0$ is equal to the function is injective

Comment: Thank you. So the condition that the rg of D$\Phi$ has to be maximum implies (i think for some mean-value generalized theorem) that vectors which map to 0 are an m-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Actually I'm not an expert in this topic, can you give your definition of your rank of not linear functions btw are you german?

Comment: I my opinion you are talking about (linear) functionals (see here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form) and there is a good theory in functional analysis maybe add this tag to your question